# How to deserialize diffrents formats of date: YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM

Tags: java, json, api, jackson

I have list of json objects,one of the fields is date. The problem is that the dates are written in diffrent ways in json.

most of them looks like:

```
 "publishedDate": "2005-01-28"
 "publishedDate": "2011-08-29"
 "publishedDate": "2016-04-19"
```

But some of them is like:

```
"publishedDate": "1998-11"
"publishedDate": "2001-01"
```

My java object field to which i want to parse

```
private Date publishedDate;
```

I got this error:

```
 Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2001-01": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2001-01': Cannot parse date "2001-01": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd', parsing fails (leniency? null))
```

Comment: What would you expect to be a reasonable deserialization of your sample data?

Comment: Don't use the `java.util.Date` class or the `Calendar` class. Deserialize into objects from the `java.time` package. Now, for us to help us, you have to show the code you used, best as [mcve].

Comment: Thats because "2001-01" doesn't match "yyyy-MM-dd" the day is never specified in the JSON, you are most likely using a different format when adding and when retrieving

Comment: @OughtToPrevail If OP used Jackson for both building and parsing the JSON, there very likely wouldn't be a problem like this. In all probability, OP is trying to parse a JSON text from a *third party*. Don't assume that JSON is just used for local storage. It is more often used for data exchange.

Comment: So do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Remigiusz1998 First, answer the question in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099794/how-to-deserialize-diffrents-formats-of-date-yyyy-mm-dd-and-yyyy-mm#comment98834609_56099794). What do you expect the result of parsing to be? Simply parsing to the first of the month, so `1998-11` parses as `1998-11-01` and you lose track of the fact that the day-of-month wasn't provided? Or is that an important part of the value?

Comment: @Andreas I would like parse it to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: "2005-01-28" and "1998-11" are two different animal. One is a date, to be represented by the `LocalDate` class. The other is a year-month, to be represented by the `YearMonth` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write custom deserialiser for a `Date` and in both cases properly convert to expected date. Below you can find simple example how to do that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<List<Item>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Item>>() {
        };
        List<Item> readValue = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, typeReference);
        System.out.println(readValue);

    }
}

class DifferentFormatsDateJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private DateTimeFormatter localDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private DateTimeFormatter yearMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM");


    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        try {
            if (value.length() == 7) {
                YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(value, yearMonthFormatter);
                return convertToDateViaInstant(yearMonth.atDay(1));
            } else {
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(value, localDateFormatter);
                return convertToDateViaInstant(localDate);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Date convertToDateViaInstant(LocalDate dateToConvert) {
        return Date.from(dateToConvert.atStartOfDay()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toInstant());
    }
}

class Item {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DifferentFormatsDateJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Date publishedDate;

    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(Date publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "publishedDate=" + publishedDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above program for `JSON` payload:

```
[
  {
    "publishedDate": "2005-01-28"
  },
  {
    "publishedDate": "1998-11"
  }
]
```

Prints:

```
[Item{publishedDate=Fri Jan 28 00:00:00 CET 2005}, Item{publishedDate=Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 CET 1998}]
```